# Duplicate records returned from table with no duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, duplication, isolation-level

I have a stored procedure that queries a busy queue table that is used to distribute work in our system. The table in question has a primary key on WorkID and no duplicates.

A simplified version of the query is:

```
INSERT INTO #TempWorkIDs (WorkID)
SELECT
        W.WorkID

    FROM
        dbo.WorkTable W

    WHERE
        (@bool_param = 0 AND
        ((W.InProgress = 0
         AND ISNULL(W.UserID, -1) != @userid_param
         AND (@bool_filtered = 0
              OR W.TypeID IN (SELECT TypeID FROM #Types AS t)))
         OR 
         (@bool_param = 1
          AND W.InProgress = 1
          AND W.UserID != @userid_param)
        OR
        (@Auto_Param = 0
         AND W.UserID = @userid_param)))
         OR
         (@bool_param = 1 AND W.UserID = @userid_param)
    OPTION
        (RECOMPILE)
```

The `#Types` table is populated earlier in the procedure.

As I said, `WorkTable` is busy, and sometimes while this query is running I **SUSPECT** one of the records is moving from one set of filters in the `WHERE` to another. Specifically, this happens when someone starts to work on an item, and the `W.InProgress` changes from 0 to 1. When this happens I get a duplicate key violation when I try to add a primary key to the temp table this query is inserting into.

I have confirmed in the query plan generated when the error occurs that there is no parallelism, the isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`, and there are no duplicate records in the source table. You can also see there are no `JOIN`s or other way to get cartesian products in here.

This is the anonymized query plan:

[image]

The question is, **what is causing the duplicates and how can I get it to stop?**

I think `READ COMMITTED` should work here, I need locking. I am almost positive the dupes occur when the `InProgress` bit on a record changes while I'm querying. I know this because the table stores the time of that change and it's within milliseconds of when I query and get the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some tricky scenarios which can result in the same row being read twice from an index, even under [the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level).

Your query does not qualify for an [allocation order scan,](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/allocation-order-scans) so the storage engine will read the data from the table in the order of the clustered key.

For your table, you have the `InProgress` as the first column of the clustered key. It's likely that you're getting row or page locks as you scan through the table. If you read a row near the start of the scan, release the lock on it, that row is updated such that `InProgress` changes from 0 to 1, and then the row is read again in a different page then you could see duplicate `WorkID` values from your query.

There are lots of workarounds. You could insert into a heap and simply remove duplicate values. You could add a `DISTINCT` to the query. You could also enable a row-versioning isolation level, to provide a stable view of the committed state of the database, either as at the beginning of the transaction ([snapshot isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-performance/the-snapshot-isolation-level)), or as at the beginning of the statement ([read committed snapshot isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation)).

Perhaps it's appropriate to add locking hints or to change the structure of the table. For a rather fun solution (probably not appropriate for production), you could try reading the index backwards. This can be done with a superfluous `TOP` along with an `ORDER BY`. Below is a very simple demo to illustrate the point:

```
CREATE TABLE #WorkTable (
    InProgress TINYINT NOT NULL,
    WorkID INT NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY (InProgress, WorkID)
);

INSERT INTO #WorkTable WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT (RN - 1) / 5000, RN
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) t
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

The following query has the Ordered:false property but it'll still read the data in clustered key order:

```
SELECT WorkId
FROM #WorkTable;
```

However, the following query will read the data in reverse clustered order:

```
SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) WorkId
FROM #WorkTable
ORDER BY InProgress DESC, WorkId DESC;
```

We can see this by looking at the scan properties:

[image: backwards scan]

For your table, this means that if a row is updated such that `InProgress` changes from 0 to 1 it will be far less likely that it'll show up twice. It may not show up at all which could be a different problem.